# Angular material dialog and ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, architecture, angular-material, ngrx

I'm working on a new Angular 6 application, with Ngrx and Angular material.
I'm creating the base app that will be used by many devs in my company. My problem is on the dialog redux system that I want to create.

I will start by share my actual code and I will explain the problem and what I tried.

My goal : Anywhere in my app, I want to simply call an action that will open a custom dialog (specific to each feature). The app should open multiple fullscreen dialogs.

**Here is my simplified architecture :**

```
AppModule
CoreModule
DialogsModule (StoreModule.forFeature('dialog', dialogReducer) / Effects.forFeature([DialogEffects]))
    FeatureAModule (contains specific dialogs component)
    FeatureBModule (contains specific dialogs component)
```

**That I want, anywhere in my app :**

```
// Random Feature
 openDialog(): void {
    const payload = {
       componentOrTemplateRef: MyDialogComponent, // The dialog, create by dev, in a specific feature
       config: {
          id: 'my-custom-id',
          data: {
             ... // MAT_DIALOG_DATA
          }
       }
    };
    this.store.dispatch(new OpenDialogAction(payload));
}
```

**My actual dialog Redux :**

***dialog.action.ts***

```
export enum DialogActionTypes {
  OPEN = '[DIALOG] OPEN',
  SAVE_REF = '[DIALOG] SAVE_REF' // use to store dialog reference in the ngrx store
  CLOSE = '[DIALOG] CLOSE'
}

export type DialogAction = OpenDialogAction | SaveRefDialogAction | CloseDialogAction;

export interface OpenDialogPayload {
  componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<any>;
  config: MatDialogConfig;
}

export interface CloseDialogPayload {
  dialogId: string;
  responseData?: any;
}

export class OpenDialogAction implements Action {
  readonly type = DialogActionTypes.OPEN;

  constructor(public payload: OpenDialogPayload) {}
}

export class SaveRefDialogAction implements Action {
  readonly type = DialogActionTypes.SAVE_REF;

  constructor(public payload: MatDialogRef<any>) {}
}

export class CloseDialogAction implements Action {
  readonly type = DialogActionTypes.CLOSE;

  constructor(public payload: CloseDialogPayload) {}
}
```

***dialog.reducer.ts***

```
export interface DialogState {
  refs: Array<{ id: string, ref: MatDialogRef<any> }>;
}

const initialState: DialogState = {
  refs: []
};

export function dialogReducer(state: DialogState = initialState, action: DialogAction): DialogState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DialogActionTypes.SAVE_REF:
      return { ...state, refs: [...state.refs, { id: action.payload.id, ref: action.payload }] };
    case DialogActionTypes.CLOSE:
      return { ...state, refs: state.refs.filter(ref => ref.id !== action.payload.dialogId) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// DialogState Selector
export const getDialogState = createFeatureSelector('dialog');

// DialogState property selectors
export const getDialogRefById = (id: string) => createSelector(getDialogState, (state: DialogState) => state.refs.find(ref => ref.id === id).ref);
```

***dialog.effects.ts***

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogEffects {
  @Effect()
  openDialog$: Observable<SaveRefDialogAction> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DialogActionTypes.OPEN),
    map((action: OpenDialogAction) => action.payload),
    switchMap((payload: OpenDialogPayload) => of(this.dialog.open(payload.componentOrTemplateRef, payload.config))),
    map((dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>) => new SaveRefDialogAction(dialogRef))
  );

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  closeDialog$: Observable<{}> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DialogActionTypes.CLOSE),
    map((action: CloseDialogAction) => action.payload),
    tap((payload: CloseDialogPayload) => this.dialog.getDialogById(payload.dialogId).close(payload.responseData)),
    mapTo(of())
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

I had a problem with feature's custom dialog components. They were not recognized by DialogsModule (they must be on entryComponents). So, I created a static method `withComponents` that return a ModuleWithProviders and populate entryComponents with the injection token ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('dialog', dialogReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([DialogEffects])
  ]
})
export class DialogsModule {
  static withComponents(components: any) ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: DialogsModule,
        providers: [{ provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, useValue: components, multi: true }]
    };
  }
}
```

**The Problem**

All of my feature with custom dialog need to import DialogsModule... But, DialogEffects will be instanciated each times (If I have 3 modules that must imports DialogsModule, DialogEffects will be instanciate 3 times).

How can I have a correct material dialog manager without this problem and the entryComponents problem ? I'm open for any suggestions.

Thank you by advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can use forRoot and forFeature for the module. [Link here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

For the root module you add the services to be singleton (like effects). For the feature module you can add the others.

You can use the singleton service with `providedIn: 'root'` but I don't know actually if it's working with NgRx effects.

P.S. On the other hand if you restore the state with HMR the modals won't stay open.